# Possibility to copy the file in different Output Dir

Tags: .net

can I copy the executable file generated in two separated output folder?

This is the script i used:

[Setup]

**OutputDir=C:\Users\admin\desktop**

i would copy in a second folder too, for example

***OutputDir = C:\Users\admin\desktop\New***

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with post-build event, Right click on the poject file in visual studio -> properties -> build events -> Post-build event command line. Here you can type your own command E.g: XCOPY, robocopy, etc.